# NSData's writeToFile method failing with server address

Tags: cocoa, nsdata

I am trying to write an NSData object to a directory like so;

```
[myData writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.txt", path, filename] atomically:YES];
```

I receive no errors or warnings but I am assuming the write fails because the `path` variable has the format of `afp://10.0.0.20/username/Desktop`. I am connected to the networked share.

Do I need to modify the string or take a different approach here?

**EDIT: Tried the following approach after recommendation but it failed**

```
NSMutableURLRequest *post = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"afp://10.0.0.20/username/Desktop/filename.txt"]];
[post setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[post setHTTPBody:horreumImageDataNewThread];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:post returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

TIA,
Ricky.

Comment: That's a URL, not a file. However, the documentation for writeToURL:atomically: states that only file:// URLs are supported. You probably need to take a different path.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you getting the afp `path` string from? You would normally write to a networked volume by using a path like:

```
/Volumes/NameOfMountedVolume/path/to/file
```

Also, you should use the `-stringByAppendingPathComponent:` method of `NSString` to concatenate paths:

```
NSString* fullPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I did a bit of digging for NSURLRequests and modified my existing post. 

My new approach won't work either, does anyone have any ideas as to why? Thanks, Ricky.